# CertUtil | How CertUtil -verifykeys works internally?

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption, pki, certutil

I have a CA certificate in Local Machine Certificate Store. 
When I run this command - `enter code here`

*`certutil -verifyKeys`*  gives `Key "KEYNAME" verifies as the public key for Certificate "KEYNAME" V0.0`

`Signature test FAILED`
`CertUtil: -verifykeys command FAILED: 0x80070057 
(WIN32: 87 ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER)`

`CertUtil: The parameter is incorrect`

MSDN says `certutil -verifykeys` - Verify public/private key set.

I was just wondering how it verifies these keys ?
Eager to know the internal working of this command.

Comment: What command did you provide in Command prompt?

Comment: certutil -verifykeys

Comment: This command also needs some parameter. See the help with `certutil -?`

Comment: by default it says : "If no arguments are specified, each signing CA cert is verified against its private key." I have only single CA cert. I just wanted to know how it verifies it internally ?

Answer (score 0):

It performs an signing operation using the registered provider and then tries to verify the signed text using the public key stored in the certificate.

Since i was using my own custom provider thus i saw a signing request falling on my provider, but no verification request. Thus i conclude that it performs signing using the registered provider but for verification it uses it own provider i.e microsoft own cng provider.